# Show that this piece-wise function is continuous at 0

Tags: analysis, continuity

Show that this function is continuous at $x=0$:

$$h(x) = \begin{cases}  \ \ x^2 \quad \text{if} \ x\not\in\Bbb{Q} \\ -x^2 \quad \text{if} \ x\in\Bbb{Q}\end{cases}$$

The answer is pretty clear to me, but the problem clearly states that I need to use a previous part of the problem which I have already proved (and is summed here):

Prove that, if $f$ is continuous at $0$ and $f(0)=0$, and $g$ is bounded (but not necessarily continuous), then $fg$ is continuous at $0$.

Thanks to anyone who can edit the formatting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the problem you cite consider:

$f(x)=x^2$

and
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 1 \quad \text{if} \ x \not\in\Bbb{Q} \\ -1 \quad \text{if} \ x\in\Bbb{Q }\end{cases}$$

Comment: I feel so dumb for not having realized this! thank you!